# Round the arrow from inner side

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I have created the following arrow using CSS, but the inner sides of my arrow are not rounded. Is there a way to do that?

```css
#arrow {
    border-right:30px solid black;
    border-bottom:30px solid black;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    margin-top:40px;
    border-radius: 1em;
    -webkit-border-radius: 1em;
-moz-border-radius: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div id="arrow"></div>
```

Comment: You will have to compose your arrow of separate blocks. But that gets more and more inefficient. Why not use an inline svg markup instead? Or a font awesome glyph?

Comment: @arkascha Thanks a lot for suggesting font awesome, although the answers below worked to fix the issue, I found that font awesome is a more convenient and easier choice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using the `:before` and `:after` selectors instead. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gopal/tvfujcLp/1/

```css
#arrow {
    width:130px;
    height:130px;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    margin-top:40px;
    position:relative;
}

#arrow:after, #arrow:before {
    content:'';
    display:block;
    height:30px;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    background:black;
    bottom:0;
    border-radius:1em;
}
#arrow:after {
    right:0;
    width:30px;
    height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="arrow"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

With an [inline svg](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG), this shape is trivial to make.
The [stroke-linejoin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-linejoin) and [stroke-linecap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-linecap) are made for the exact issue you have :

```css
svg {width: 30%;}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 7 10" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" >
  <polyline points="1 1 5 5 1 9" 
            fill="none" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="#000" 
            stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   ![enter image description here][1]
 <style>
    #arrow {
      border-right: 30px solid black;
      border-bottom: 30px solid black;
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      transform: rotate(135deg);
      margin-top: 40px;
      border-radius: 1em;
      -webkit-border-radius: 1em;
      -moz-border-radius: 1em;
      margin-left: 20px;
    }
 </style>
 <div id="arrow"></div>
```

Comment: I tried this on JSFiddle but still the same result: 
http://jsfiddle.net/a0uogod0/148/